# How to get the value from <Select> options (multiple values) and print them in <textarea> and than submit the form in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
    const handleformData = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const filedName = event.target.getAttribute("name");
        const fieldValue = event.target.value;
    
        const newFormData = { ...addFormData };
        newFormData[filedName] = fieldValue;
    
        setAddFormData(newFormData);
      };
    
<form>
        <select name="listIngr" onChange={handleformData}>
                    <option value="Apple">Flour</option>
                    <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id="textArea" name="quantity" onChange={handleformData} />
<button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

i can get the value with onChange function, but i cant implement it into the text area value

Comment: Can you show the whole component?

Comment: What's the error? You can't access the value of `textarea` in the `handleformData` function? Or do you want to print the selected option in the `textarea`? For latter, just use state to access it.

Comment: The problem was when I select something from the selector options, to immediate print that in my text area. (without me typing it in there).